# Sync data to database and render to UI in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, crud

I am new to react & JS. I need to sync data to db and use what i got from db render to UI.
Flow: CRUD in infra => sync data to db => use data from db and render to UI.
But the second function always completes first when syncDB still in status "pending". So if I detete all my db and run in very first time, I will get nothing in UI.
This is how I code:
[Sync data to db]

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    const syncDB = async () => {
      await Api.post(syncLocalDisk({vpcId, instanceId}))
    }
    syncDB()
  }, [])
```

```
const {data, isLoading, isRefetching, error, refetch} = useQuery(
    ['instance-storages', vpcId, instanceId],
    () => {
      const url = `${instanceStorages({
        vpcId,
        instanceId,
      })}`
      return Api.get(url)
    },
  )
```

How can I make sure it's syncDB first?

I have tried sync DB inside useQuery but it does not seems very logicial.

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    const syncDB = async () => {
      await Api.post(syncLocalDisk({vpcId, instanceId}))
    }
    await syncDB()
  }, [])
```

Try this.